# are mass-edits of minor issues considered bad practice?

Tags: discussion, edits

I just noticed lot of old java EE questions are being pushed at the top of the posts. It seems to be one user [mass editing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472792/arjan-tijms?tab=activity&sort=all&page=1) all java EE related posts from mentioning "JEE" and use "Java EE" instead. To me, this is a bit bothering as there are lot of new posts showing up as updated although there aren't really any changes. Are there any practices or something on how to react to such a thing? Or is this common and just happens from time to time, "deal with it"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any practices or something on how to react to such a thing?

Yes. Leave them alone, unless there is more you can improve in the post (removal of salutation, better spelling and grammar, improved formatting etc...), otherwise these would be classed as "too minor" - as suggested edits they are likely to get rejected.

And if they don't get rejected, or you have enough reputation to just edit, the edits would bump the posts to the front page. Multiple edits (in particular by multiple people) can also make the post into a wiki post, meaning the OP will not gain any reputation from it anymore.

> Or is this common and just happens from time to time, "deal with it"?

Pretty much.

Comment: And even if you really end up making such edits, there is no rush. Just a couple each day will suffice. Which will also give you more than enough time to consider each post in its entirety.

Comment: Just to clarify - are you saying I should leave alone people doing such edits, or I shouldn't be doing such edits? The case here is that someone else is doing a lot of editing like that. The thing what I tried to ask was that is it considered harmful behaviour. Was that a 'yes' or 'no'?

Comment: @eis - It was not clear to me which you were asking. But the answer to both is - leave it alone. You really shouldn't do such edits, but if someone else does... let them. If you feel they are overdoing it, you can comment or even flag for moderator attention if you feel they should be involved.

Answer (score 4):

It's OK to do mass-edits as much as it's OK for a mass of people to do one edit each.

So long as the edits are of good quality. I often find a certain pattern of mistakes and attempt to do a string of edits in a long grueling session, but rather than just fix the problem patterns I used to find the posts, I try to:

- make the title more succinct
- disambiguate title and body
- format block and inline code sections properly
- embed links
- optimize tags
- improve spelling and grammar

So long as these kind of things are being done, then the more edits the better! It improves the quality of the post and the site in general.